# Why does the increment only run once?

Tags: unity, c#

I've made an `Event Trigger` when I have written a script that makes something disappear when it's hit. In addition to that I've an increment in that method that should increment each time something is hit, but it only increment the first time. Can somebody tell me why this is happening and what I should do in order to solve it?

```
 public void Hit()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Hits++;
    text.text = Hits.ToString();
}
```

So every time something is hit this method runs, but it only increments the first time.

Comment: are you destroying the gameobject before you increment? Looks like it.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon should not be an issue as he called `Destroy` instead of `DestroyImmediate`. It could very well be due to the codes that he did not show.

Comment: You should show how this code is used...

Comment: It seems to me that `Hits` is a `static` variable, otherwise your question really makes no sense. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a guess since we'd really need to see where the 'Hits' value is coming from, but I'm guessing that is a field of this gameObject, so when you Destroy this gameObject the value 'Hits' is going away. What you want is for 'Hits' to be shared across multiple objects, like with a static or something.

Answer (score 0):

This event it's called when the gameobject is hit, but the first thing you are doing is destroy the object. `Destroy` lasts a couple miliseconds before detroy the object itselfs, so the whole method is executed, but there will be no object the next hit so neither the method.

I can't help you anymore because I don't know what are you trying to do. If you put your code, where is attached this code (and the gameObject) and what you want to do maybe I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

When you make this run, there are 2 scenarios,

1:
The object gets destroyed, moves on and does ++Hits;.

2:
No object is hit and it is stuck destroying a blank tile.

(I`m a noobie)